# how to log cosmos RUs usage selectively along with a transaction identifier using Cosmos DB Spring data SQL api

Tags: java, azure, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using following spring data cosmos library. But we would like to selectively log cosmos RUs based on a requestId or transaction Id for tracing only if Rus usage of a given call is more than threshold. How to achieve this with spring data cosmos

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```